# How to use DI in a fixture class

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I want to create a fixture for categories, but I get the error
Could you elaborate on how di works in Symfony. The documentation didn't tell me much.
in `config / services.yaml` the standard code is already specified which seems to solve the di problem

```
class CategoryFixtures extends \Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture
{
    private $category;

    public function __construct(
        \App\Entity\Category $category
    ) {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function load(\Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->addMainCategories($manager);
    }

    private function addMainCategories($manager) {
        $mainCategoriesArray = ['111', '222', '333', '444', '555'];

        foreach ($mainCategoriesArray as $categoryName) {
            $this->category->setName($categoryName);
            $manager->persist($this->category);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Error

```
Cannot autowire service "App\DataFixtures\CategoryFixtures": argument "$category" of method "__construct()" references class "App\Entity\Category" but no such service exists.
```

Comment: You can't inject an entity, entity is not a service.

Answer (score 0):

DI isn't really the issue here.

Untested code to create 5 Category entities:

```
use App\Entity\Category;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

// Creates Category entities Category0, Category1...
class CategoryFixtures extends AbstractFixture
{
    private $mainCategoriesArray = ['111', '222', '333', '444', '555'];
    
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $name = 'Category' . $i;
            $$name = new Category();
            $$name->setName($this->mainCategoriesArray[$i]);
            $manager->persist($$name);
        }
        
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't add entity via constructor?

Comment: Do you mean something like a service `CreateFixtureEntity($class, $properties)`? That should be possible. Why or why not to do that is not in my skill set.